# Send SMS/text messages from Windows through USB + iPhone?

Tags: iphone, windows, usb, sms

I use the [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/) (MPE) utility to send SMS/text message from my Windows host through my Android smartphone connected to the computer with a USB cable. It's a no-brainer.

A friend of mine has an iPhone and a Windows laptop: I was wondering if there's an equivalent to MPE that can work with an iPhone:

1. Runs on Windows and iPhone
2. Windows and iPhone connected through USB cable

Connecting both hosts (Windows laptop + iPhone smartphone) to wifi just for this is overkill.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without jail breaking the iPhone. There are numerous tweaks available on Cydia (jail break equivalent of App Store) that enable this functionality.

iPhones and a Mac computer will both send SMS messages natively from your phone number, but this isn't available on Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I'll investigate how to jailbreak and if texting can be done from Windows